# What does Hinduism say about third-gendered people?

Tags: belief, gender

Recently, gay rights have been a very hot topic, and some politicians say that they are un-natural and against Hindutva. But how? I mean I don't remember any Veda or religious book saying anything against a third gender. And even the Mahabharata has a transgender character (Shikhandi). Is there anything in the Vedas/Upanishads/Puranas for the acceptance or non-acceptance of third-gendered people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [hrc.org](http://www.hrc.org/resources/entry/stances-of-faiths-on-lgbt-issues-hinduism)

> The erotic sculptures on ancient Hindu temples at Khajuraho and
>   Konarak, and the sacred texts in Sanskrit constitute irrefutable
>   evidence that a whole range of sexual behavior was known to ancient
>   Hindus. The tradition of representing same-sex desire in literature
>   and art continued in medieval Hinduism.
>
> [Ayyappan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyappan) is a Hindu deity who is believed to be an incarnation of
>   Dharma Sasta, the offspring of Shiva and Vishnu (in the form of
>   Mohini)
>
> A number of 14th-century texts in Sanskrit and Bengali (including the
>   [Krittivasa Ramayana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krittivasi_Ramayan), a devotional text still extremely popular
>   today) narrate how hero-king Bhagiratha, who brought the sacred river
>   Ganga from heaven to earth, was miraculously born to and raised by two
>   co-widows, who made love together with divine blessing. These texts
>   explain that his name Bhagiratha comes from the word bhaga (vulva),
>   because he was born of two vulvas.
>
> Another sacred text, the fourth-century [Kamasutra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_Sutra), emphasizes
>   pleasure as the aim of intercourse. It categorizes men who desire
>   other men as a “third nature.” The text goes on to subdivide such men
>   into masculine and feminine types and describes their lives and
>   typical occupations (including flower sellers, masseurs and
>   hairdressers). The Kamasutra also includes a detailed description of
>   oral sex between men and refers to long-term unions between male
>   partners.
>
> In Hindu mythology, ritual, and art, the power of androgyny or sexual
>   ambiguity is a frequent and significant theme. Bahuchara Mata, the
>   main object of hijra veneration, is a version of the Mother Goddess,
>   for whose sake they undergo emasculation. In return for their
>   emasculation the Goddess gives them the power to bless people with
>   fertility, granting them an important religious role in births and
>   marriages.

[Iravan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iravan)/Aravan is a patron god of well-known transgender communities called Ali (also Aravani in South India, and Hijra throughout South Asia).

> On A temple festival of Aravan, Hijras and aravanis are ceremonially
>   married to the idol of Aravan (and hence the name Aravani is a term of
>   identity that many hijras adopt). Often hijras come to Koovagam with
>   their lovers or ‘husbands’ and on the penultimate night of the
>   festival, they all exerience a night of ‘marital bliss’, ( Source:[newindianexpress.com](http://www.newindianexpress.com/magazine/article59561.ece?service=print))

So if Hinduism have so many example of Trans-reference and even Kamasutra and Khajuraho and Konarak also includes them and no refrense say its adharma or unantural then that claims of politician also proves wrong. Some claims also said that it British people who influenced the non-homosexuality movement. And as i already included from link text, Hijra's is said to be divine not a disease.

Comment: Your arguments have lots of flaws. To begin with, no such example can *prove* anything. Sita in Ramayana was abducted -- Would you say, "Abducting others' wives is allowed in Hinduism"?
Apart from that, for example, Vishnu is not male (neither Female, nor third, nor both). He/She/It is beyond gender. Vishnu's avatars, however, have genders. As such, Mohini, a female, had sex with Shiva, who is (normally) a man. If you want, I can explain in a complete answer/blog post.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Rama killed Ravana for abducting a lady but Iravan/Aravan  is a poplar god among third gender people and nobody bashed Shikahndi for his orientation.

Comment: You completely misunderstood me. My point is, just because something was mentioned in an ancient text does not mean it was accepted .

Comment: Besides, Shikhandi was a man, who had sex with a woman (his wife). Why would people bash him?

Comment: @pushpen.paul he was not "born as man", get a fact check before bashing others posts. If you have better answer give it and move on, don't fight with others if they can't agree with you.

Comment: He was born as a man. He was a woman (Amba) in his last birth, and he had recollections of his old memory as a woman. Please check facts your before you claim anything. I am not bashing anyone, I am humbly pointing out flaws in your logic(!).

Comment: @pushpen.paul so you are telling me bhisma is liar? because he didn't attacked on a women

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69725/discussion-between-pushpen-paul-and-ankit-sharma).

Comment: Please, at least for once, go through the great epic. Vishma abducted Amba (unlike Ravana, he was not killed) along with her sisters, Ambika & Ambalika to get them married to his brothers, Chitrangad & Vichitraviryya. Amba, however, fell in love with Vishma, and refused to marry his brothers. Vishma, having an oath of celibacy, denied. Then Amba prayed to Parashuram (avatar of Vishnu, guru of Vishma) to force him to marry. Vishma refused, she repeated, he refused again. After a long turn of events, she got boon from Shiva, in next life she will be a man so that he can take revenge on Vishma...

Comment: So, she took birth as Shikhandi, and remembered everything. Knowing all these, Vishma denied to attack *him*.

Comment: Shikhandi was female

Comment: Anyway, even if Shikhandi was a *woman*, it does not prove that woman marrying woman was allowed.

Comment: @pushpen.paul so?

Comment: So, you know nothing about anything. And you won't admit that.

Comment: Oral sex? I think it is prohibited.

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially there is nothing against third-genderism or any other sexuality in Hinduism or you can also say Sanatan Dharma. In fact the basic belief in Hinduism is we are all living out our karmas on earth and accordingly we get bodies on earthly plain and in fact it is against the core principles of Hinduism to discriminate against third gender people. But the modern day Hindu right is completely ignorant about Hindu scriptures and on this issue are guided more by their own prejudices rather than by what is mentioned in the scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

> Ila (Sanskrit: इल) or Ilā (Sanskrit: इला) is an androgyne in Hindu
>   mythology, known for their sex changes. As a man, he is known as Ila
>   or Sudyumna and as a woman, is called Ilā. Ilā is considered the chief
>   progenitor of the Lunar dynasty of Indian kings - also known as the
>   Ailas ("descendants of Ilā").
>
> While many versions of the tale exist, Ila is usually described as a
>   daughter or son of Vaivasvata Manu and thus the sibling of Ikshvaku,
>   the founder of the Solar Dynasty. In versions in which Ila is born
>   female, she changes into a male form by divine grace soon after her
>   birth. After mistakenly entering a sacred grove as an adult, Ila is
>   either cursed to change his/her gender every month or cursed to become
>   a woman. As a woman, Ilā married Budha, the god of the planet Mercury
>   and the son of the lunar deity Chandra (Soma), and bore him a son
>   called Pururavas, the father of the Lunar dynasty. After the birth of
>   Pururavas, Ilā is transformed into a man again and fathered three
>   sons.
>
> In the Vedas, Ilā is praised as Idā (Sanskrit: इडा), goddess of
>   speech, and described as mother of Pururavas.

Read more on this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ila_(Hinduism)

Comment: Please add another source in addition to Wikipedia. For example, if you know the Purana in which this story is told, please provide a relevant quote from it.

Answer (score -2):

There are 11 (eleven) genders as per Hinduism. Vedagamic scriptures talk about the lifestyle a kid/teen has to live for the gender to revealed to that being.

Comment: And what are they? Can you please elaborate? I only know about three.

Comment: I don't have the list for all of them, but think about it, in the cycle of rebirth once can change genders, sometimes the genders transit from one to another. Transition is 2 ways M -> F and F-> M, there are complete beings i.e. have both male and female components completely in them, there are "evolved" beings they have only a fraction of certain hormones. Forcing them all into 3 broad categories is violence against them.

Comment: Akhil, you're going to need at least one source for such claims

Comment: majority of Hinduism scriptures are not digitized ... till that happens ???