# A few questions on homosexuality and hinduism

Tags: karma, sin, homosexuality

Sorry this is a taboo topic but I have 2 questions

1. What are some examples of bad karma that result in a birth as a homosexual ?It seems that it can only be a bad karma as good karma can't possibly result in a sexual deviance birth.

Someone told me, being a cause in separation of a husband and wife in past life, results in a birth as a homosexual in this life. As one was cause of separation between 2 lovers, one is cursed to be loveless in this life as a homosexual.

2. Is the third-gender mentioned in scriptures referring to homosexuals ?

Comment: One can change one's sexual orientation using Vipassana meditation.

Comment: What's Vipassana? @Rajas.

Comment: As per our scriptures , i mean hindu scriptures, homosexuality is inborn and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Surya Meditation technique rediscovered by Gautam Buddha to change in born instincts & also any habit wr developed in this life.

Comment: I think your second question is already asked. [Vedas and Vedic dharma on homosexuality](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8744/5212) and [What does Hinduism say about third-gendered people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/175/5212).

Comment: "someone told me cause of"...... how can you believe on "someone said/told" in matters of religion. Who is that "someone", a supreme Yogi? Secondly, there is no account of any homosexual things in Scriptures. In KamaSutra, there is hint of how a man could court with a neuter gender. And as for the 3rd gender in Scriptures, it refers to neuter gender only. The neuter gender comes out from Tamasic part of Prakriti.