# Karmic result of a gay man marrying a straight woman fraudulently

Tags: scripture, karma, homosexuality, punishment

What could be the karmic punishment of a gay man who marries woman without telling her that he's gay, but fulfills her sexual and other needs and woman doesn't doubt it? Are there any scriptures that mention karmic punishments involving such fraudulent marriages?

Comment: the question is not if homosexuality is a part of hinduism or not . The question is about karmic consequences of him marrying an unsuspecting woman

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal advice questions are not allowed on this site.  If you want to take out the personal details and make the question more general, then I'd be happy to reopen your question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes sir please .

Comment: OK, I edited you question and reopened it.

Comment: I would like to say: one real [hindu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu) (PLEASE READ IT - YOU NEED IT!) can't be a homosexual. If he is a homosexual, then he is not a hindu! Then he is indian person, but not a hindu!

Comment: And this question is a [DUBLICATE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24145)!

Comment: @Bharata , no it isn't . This question is about karmic consequence of marrying someone without informing them of true nature

Comment: it is sad to see how closed minded we have become to not even debate on a topic :(

Comment: this forum is not intended for giving opinions. please read forum rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A few questions on homosexuality and hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/a-few-questions-on-homosexuality-and-hinduism)

Comment: You are asking two different and unrelated questions. First is karmic result and second is references to incidents and stories. You should only ask one question per post. Otherwise your question will be closed as too broad. *Limit your question to a single topic*. Also it is not about close minded etc, site is not for debates and discussions. You ask questions and we answer. [chat] is for discussion.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Make it as an answer! :-)

Comment: No, Karma is incurred only when pain is caused. There is nothing sacred about marriage, but the oath taken invoking God during marriage ritual is sacred. And violation of that oath incurs Karma. Marriage of any kind itself has no Karma

Comment: @Krishna Earlier the question was closed. So had to post a comment instead. Anyways posted as an answer now. :-)

Comment: @Curious if you are satisfied with any answer then click on check mark under it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraudulent marriages may distinctly fall under ***"PishAcha"* marriage** (sub demonic), which is the lowest category among all types of marriages. According to [Manusmruti, chapter 3](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu03.htm), among 8 types of marriages, 2 of them, viz. *Asura & PishAcha* -- should never by practiced.

> 34. When (a man) by stealth seduces a girl who is sleeping, intoxicated, or **disordered in intellect**, that is the eighth, **the most base and sinful rite of the Pisakas**.
> 35. But in these (Institutes of the sacred law) three of the five (last) are declared to be lawful and two unlawful; the Paisaka and the Asura (rites) must never be used.

If a gay person, succeeds in seducing a girl, because her intellect couldn't help her find the reality, then he may fall under extremely sinful marriage as above.
**Karmik punishment could be hellish treatment** in present life or afterlife.

---

Having said above, the case which you described doesn't seem that sinful to me. Because the gay man is satisfying the straight woman's physical needs.

Comment: What is Pishaka? Shouldn't it be Pishacha? The verse is सुप्तां मत्तां प्रमत्तां वा रहो यत्रोपगच्छति । स पापिष्ठो विवाहानां **पैशाचश्**चाऽष्टमोऽधमः ॥ .

Comment: And the verse is actually talking about a girl who is **sleeping, intoxicated, or mentally ill(Pramatta)** . And it is highly not the chance that the girl in the main question is mentally ill.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I would say that "mentally ill" is a very specified translation of the verse. We may generalize it to "**mentally immature**". Moreover, here we are trying to match the today's time. Every union of man & woman is a marriage. The above marriage will either fall under "Gandharva" or "PishAcha". Due to premises of the Qn, it seems better fitted with the latter.

Comment: But Pramatta means mentally ill or someone who has lost senses of mind, not immature. Even the translation is saying disordered by intellect = mentally disordered. Even if it is immature, then also the girl in question may not be immature. And kindly correct Pishacha word also. In fact, Pishaka is not even a word.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, if you see its meaning in an [online dictionary](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=pramattatA&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3), then it doesn't even mention "illness". Rather it shows the dizzy state of mind, which is similar to sleepiness. Here I have tried to interpret it generalized. Instead of physical sleepiness, it's mental sleepiness, viz. immaturity. If we go literally by meaning, then the marriage in Qn may not match any category at all. BTW "Pisakas" is translated in the scripture & is not mine. Probably they have some convention about how to pronounce.

Comment: See here - [Pramatta](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=Pramatta&direct=se) , two of its meanings are insane and mad . And most of them are mental inactivity or dizziness, not a single is immaturity. And regarding Pisakas, it is wrong word. Translator has made wrong transliteration. Pishacha should be written like Pishacha.

Comment: that sounds scary @iammilind

Answer (score 3):

According to Manusmriti:

> A husband under no circumstances shall betray the trust, respect and honor of his wife, for another woman; for it will bring shame to himself, his family and wrath of God in afterlife.

So, as you can read Manusmriti law doesn't allow it and tells about consecutive punishment.

Taken from [laws-for-husband-and-wife-in-hinduism-manusmriti](https://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/laws-for-husband-and-wife-in-hinduism-manusmriti/14)

Answer (score 0):

Scripture does not go into the the exact karmic consequences of any particular action. It only gives a general guidelines as to whether actions are sattvic, rajasic, or tamasic. The substance of your question is - what if one commits a life-long fraudulent act? Is not such a person being a liar in his actions to their family, society in general, as well as to the other person? Is not such a person being a hypocrite in order to gratify their own desires? Such an act is tamasic in nature. Krishna says in the Gita (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 14.16 The fruit of a good action is said to be good and clean; the fruit of rajas is pain, and the fruit of tamas is ignorance.
>
> 14.18 ...and those who are steeped in tamas, being weighted down by the tendencies of the lowest guna, go downward.
>
> 16.4 Ostentation, arrogance, and self-conceit; anger, rudeness, and ignorance--these belong to him who is born to the heritage of the demons.
>
> 16.7 Men of demonic nature know not what to do and what to refrain from doing. Purity in not in them, nor good conduct, nor truth.
>
> 16.8 They say: "The world is devoid of truth, without a moral basis, and without a God. It is brought about by the union of male and female, and lust alone is its cause: What else?
>
> 16.10 Giving themselves up to insatiable desires, full of hypocrisy, pride, and arrogance, they hold false views through delusion and act with impure resolve.
>
> 16.11-12 ...looking on the gratification of desire as their highest goal...given up wholly to lust and wrath, they strive by unjust means, to amass wealth for their satisfaction of their passions.
>
> 16.16 ...bewildered by many fancies, entangled in the meshes of delusion, addicted to the gratification of lust, they fall into a loathsome hell.
>
> 16.17 ...they ostentatiously perform sacrifices, which are so only in name, in utter disregard for precepts.
>
> 16.19 These cruel haters, these evil-doers, these vilest of men, I hurl always into the wombs of the demons in the cycle of births and deaths.
>
> 16.20 Having fallen into the wombs of demons and being deluded from birth to birth, they never attain Me, O son of Kunti, but go farther down to the lowest state.
>
> 16.21 Three are the gateways of this hell leading to the ruin of the self--lust, wrath, and greed. Therefore let man renounce these three.

Scripture tells us to control our passions, including lust--whether that lust is for a man or a woman.